# USB drive completely broken after iso burn. How to fix?

Tags: usb, partitioning

So, I attempted to burn an image of Elementary os to an 8gb flash drive. The image was about 1gb. This appears to have created a 1gb partition on the drive with the rest as unallocated space. That is only the first problem. The 1gb partition is seemingly corrupt. I cannot format it, or even resize it to fill the whole drive. I was thinking that I could restore the flash drive to it's original state by burning a blank 8gb image to it. But, alas, I have no clue where to get / how to make one of those. Can someone help me restore this drive to a blank ntfs, fat32, or exfat filesystem. Thanks in advance. Let me know if I should put more info up, and what info to put up.

(I know I'm kinda stupid for not creating a backup image, but I am still a noob in need of assistance)

Answer (score 1):

The instructions by AndyO had problems because clean and format quick were failing for access denied errors. I had to run the HDD LLF Low Level Format Tool (https://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/) to zero out the drive completely and then running his instructions fixed the drive for general use.

To add one step to the end of his steps, to see the drive in Explorer, go to Computer Management, right click the drive, and select `Change Drive Letter and Paths`

Answer (score 0):

```
Start->Run
diskmgmt.msc
Find the USB stick
```

Try Right Clicking the partition and deleting.
if sector 0 was messed up, you may have to Right Click the left column and initialize disk.

Comment: in diskmgmt, it appears that I cannot delete the partition, nor is there an initialize disk option in the left column. I poked around the properties menu and, alas, to no avail. what does this mean? BTW let it be known that I am using windows 10, so diskmgmt may be different than previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

The in my experience most reliable and quickest way is to run `diskpart` from the command prompt.

Once you've started it (it'll have its own `DISKPART>` prompt), do the following:

`list disk` - Find the number of your USB drive.
`select disk <number of your drive>`
`list disk` - Just to ensure that the correct drive is selected (it should have an asterisk next to it), otherwise the next command would be catastrophic.
`clean`
`create partition primary`
`format quick` - Will use default settings. You could at this point also format through Explorer or however you usually format your drives.