# USB showing in Device Manager->Disk drives but not in This PC

Tags: usb-flash-drive

So, I just recently bought a new 32GB Transcend USB because I wanted to install Ubuntu to my laptop, and I need to burn the ISO file. At first, the USB works perfectly fine. Unfortunately, the process did not terminate successfully and now the USB is practically useless. If I insert the USB, it will not appear in This PC. If I open command prompt(as admin) and run diskpart, the command prompt will get stuck forever until I remove the USB. If I open Disk Management while the USB is inserted, it will also freeze until the USB is removed. However, if I open Device Manager, the USB will appear in the Disk Drive. In Device Manager, I tried updating the driver but it says that it already has the driver installed. Can someone help me fix this issue? because I don't think that this thing is broken. Thanks!

Comment: does this help ? https://superuser.com/a/1635850/714576

Comment: Nope, I tried installing HDDGURU but same problem again, the Device Selection Menu will not appear after I clicked continue for free (I waited for half an hour and nothing). Meanwhile, after removing the USB, it immediately appears :(

Answer (score -1):

Download your ISO then use Rufus, you can format in Explorer by right clicking and Format or you can in a number of these apps, just make sure you're formatting to the correct format for the device. i.e. FAT32.

Rufus --- https://rufus.ie  is what I started using years ago and haven't had an issue since. Before I had many a jacked up USBs and corrupted files. Seems solid, and it's been ol' reliable for me. You can run the process in Windows or the OS but I recommend using a bootable ISO burn program at the least. You'll likely have to start from scratch unless you can recover corrupted files. If it shows in device manager then your computer recognizes its existence but if you format USB into the wrong format it may show as something highly generic or literally not at all (though unlikely). You cant put anything else on the flash drive without a disk partition, if that's what you mean but messed up, it's going to act like a Disk with a near autorun-like attitude otherwise that depending on your settings requires a click or may run auto.

You may be able to troubleshoot existing USB disk in Disk Management. It should detect all connected drives, mounted or unmounted, useable or unusable.

Comment: Well, the thing is, the Disk Management window will freeze if I have the USB plugged in, and immediately works fine after unplugging the USB.